# I created a modal dialog to jump to a record in a report but I can only search for one record

Tags: vba, ms-access

I created a modal pop up with a textbox, search and a print button. The functionality is the user types an ID in the textbox the search button finds the ID in the report, the print button prints the record, everything works fine until I try and type a new ID in and click search, nothing happens.  Why?

```
Public stuID As String
Private Sub printProfile_Click()
DoCmd.OpenReport "toBeFiltered", acViewPreview, , "[stuIDOriginal] = " & stuID
DoCmd.PrintOut acSelection
End Sub

Private Sub searchID_Click()
stuID = stuIDTxt.Value
DoCmd.OpenReport "toBeFiltered", acViewPreview, , "[stuIDOriginal] = " & stuID
End Sub
```

Comment: You can't open the report if it's already open.  You'll either need to close it and reopen it, or change the filter on the report without closing it.  Docmd.Close acreport,"toBeFiltered",acsaveno   OR something like Reports!ToBeFiltered.filter = "[StudIDOriginal] =" & stuID  Then Reports!ToBeFiltered.fitlerOn = true.  The syntax may be a bit off, but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Access Report's `Print Preview` is a static snapshot of rendered output and not dynamic interface, hence it will not reflect a changed filter nor can it be searched on.

Consider changing the view to `Report View` to change the filter and then snapshot the report to `Print Preview` (but remove the filter on final view):

```
Public stuID As String
Private Sub printProfile_Click()
   DoCmd.OpenReport "toBeFiltered", acViewReport, , "[stuIDOriginal] = " & stuID
   DoCmd.OpenReport "toBeFiltered", acViewPreview
   DoCmd.PrintOut acSelection
End Sub

Private Sub searchID_Click()
  stuID = stuIDTxt.Value
  DoCmd.OpenReport "toBeFiltered", acViewReport, , "[stuIDOriginal] = " & stuID
  DoCmd.OpenReport "toBeFiltered", acViewPreview
End Sub
```